Select rows based on condition for decimal columns returns nothing
I have the following table:
CREATE TABLE `ages` (
    `id` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `min_age` decimal(4,2) NOT NULL,
    `max_age` decimal(4,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

With the following data:
INSERT INTO `ages` (`id`, `min_age`, `max_age`) VALUES
(1, 4.00, 4.30),
(2, 4.40, 4.70),
(3, 4.80, 4.11),
(4, 5.00, 5.50),
(5, 5.60, 5.11),
(6, 6.00, 6.50),
(7, 6.60, 6.11),
(8, 7.00, 7.50),
(9, 7.60, 7.11),
(10, 8.00, 8.11),
(11, 9.00, 9.11),
(12, 10.00, 10.11),
(13, 11.00, 11.11),
(14, 12.00, 12.11),
(15, 13.00, 13.11),
(16, 14.00, 14.11),
(17, 15.00, 24.11);

You can find a fiddle here to run and test queries directly: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qkbkZD2kWjpPtyv4TiZN23/0
I'm trying to get some recorde based on min_age and max_age columns but no results are returned.
Select example:
SELECT * FROM `ages`
WHERE `min_age` <= 8.6 AND `max_age` >= 8.6;

It's not working becuase the condition should match this row:



id
min_age
max_age




10
8.00
8.11



in this case 8.11 is smaller than 8.6 because this fraction represents the number of months, so I want 8.11 to be the bigger value.
How to make it work and return row with id = 10?

If the fraction should be the number of months, you should use 8.06 for 6 months, not 8.60.

Why don't you just store the number of months as an integer, rather than abusing decimals like this?

@Barmar You are totally correct I updated the column names. I used decimals to use fewer columns and get the same result if you mean to have separated columns for years and others for months

No, I mean instead of 8.06 use 102 (8 years * 12 + 6 months)

In your representation, how would you represent 8years 1 month vs 8yrs 10 months? are they both the same decimal value? check @Barmar's comment above

@tinazmu 8.1 vs 8.10 obviously :)

@Barmar HAHAHAHAHA!

This realy doesn't make sense, but just to point to some of the issues I'll answer the question with code that works with the data provided. Hope the issues will be clear and that years and months as a decimal number will be escaped one way or another - for good!

How to make it work and return row with id = 10?

--      S a m p l e    D a t a :
CREATE TABLE `ages` (
    `id` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `min_age` decimal(4,2) NOT NULL,
    `max_age` decimal(4,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `ages` (`id`, `min_age`, `max_age`) VALUES
(1, 4.00, 4.30),
(2, 4.40, 4.70),
(3, 4.80, 4.11),
(4, 5.00, 5.50),
(5, 5.60, 5.11),
(6, 6.00, 6.50),
(7, 6.60, 6.11),
(8, 7.00, 7.50),
(9, 7.60, 7.11),
(10, 8.00, 8.11),
(11, 9.00, 9.11),
(12, 10.00, 10.11),
(13, 11.00, 11.11),
(14, 12.00, 12.11),
(15, 13.00, 13.11),
(16, 14.00, 14.11),
(17, 15.00, 24.11);

... with this sample data you tryed to select the row with id = 10 using this Where clause :
...
WHERE `min_age` <= 8.6 AND `max_age` >= 8.6;
--  and you got no rows selected ...
--
-- this condition could fetch just one (1) row, 
-- the row where both min_age and max_age have the same decimal value of 8.6

... where 8.6 is 8 years and 6 months - if that is so you should extract years and months out of both min_age and max_age columns - for that you could (with an exception) create a cte like this ...
WITH
   yrs_mths AS
     ( Select   id, 
                min_age, Cast(min_age_yr as UNSIGNED) as min_age_yr, 
                Cast(Case When SubStr(min_age_mth, -1) = '0' 
                          Then SubStr(min_age_mth, 1, 1) 
                     Else min_age_mth 
                     End as UNSIGNED) as min_age_mth, 
                --
                max_age, Cast(max_age_yr as UNSIGNED) as max_age_yr,
                Cast(Case When SubStr(max_age_mth, -1) = '0' 
                          Then SubStr(max_age_mth, 1, 1) 
                     Else max_age_mth 
                     End as UNSIGNED) as max_age_mth
       From     ( Select  id, min_age, max_age,
                          SubStr(min_age, 1, InStr(min_age, '.') - 1) as min_age_yr, 
                          SubStr(min_age, InStr(min_age, '.') + 1) as min_age_mth, 
                          SubStr(max_age, 1, InStr(max_age, '.') - 1) as max_age_yr, 
                          SubStr(max_age, InStr(max_age, '.') + 1) as max_age_mth
                  From ages ) y
     )

... now you have nice and shiny integer values for years and months - BUT there is exception (mentioned in comments) - if you can make distinction between e.g. 6 year and 1 month vs 6 years and 10 months written as a decimal in the database then you handle that too in the code above cause it doesn't cope (with current syntax) with this kind of exception ...
... let's forget the exception and see how to use the above code to select the row with id = 10 using 8.6 decimal presented as years.months ...
--    M a i n    S Q L : 
SELECT    id, min_age, max_age  
FROM      yrs_mths
WHERE     ( min_age_yr < 8 OR (min_age_yr = 8 And min_age_mth <= 6) ) AND 
          ( max_age_yr > 8 OR (max_age_yr = 8 And max_age_mth >= 6) );

... if your 8.6 is 8 years and 6 months then you'll need to use OR operator twice to filter the sample data by logic described ...
/*    R e s u l t :
id  min_age max_age
-- -------- -------
10     8.00    8.11    */

See the fiddle here.


WHERE `min_age` <= 8.6 AND `max_age` >= 8.6;

It's not working because the condition should match this row:



id
min_age
max_age




10
8.00
8.11



in this case 8.11 is smaller than 8.6 because this fraction represents the number of months

Remember: you're working decimal values, which is not exactly the same as  two integers separated by a period, because the decimal value as implies a specific denominator.
It helps to understand if we emphasize the "fraction" part of the quote. When viewed as a fraction, 8.6 is and always will be 8 and 6/10ths, which is equivalent to 8 and 60/100ths. But the 8.11 value for the max_age column is only 8 and 11/100ths. 11 is not >= 60, and so the row does not and cannot match the conditional expression.
If you expected to have the 6 in 8.6 only mean 6 hundredths, instead of 60, you need to write it that way. Given these are months, where you have a max value of 11 (12 would be the next year), you can do it by using a leading 0 in each of the decimal values 9 and below, (ie:8.06). Looking at another row, (4, 5.00, 5.50) should be encoded as (4, 5.00, 5.05). For other kinds of data, with larger potential maximum values, you may need more leading zeros.
Or you could store the absolute number of months as an integer (96, 102, and 107 for 8.00, 8.06, and 8.11 respectively), so the (4, 5.00, 5.50) row would be encoded as (4, 60, 65).
